# zsh via Cygwin not working on vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Recently I tried to start using [Oh My ZSH!](http://ohmyz.sh/), looks good, but at work I can't install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), so I decided to use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/). After a few tutorial reading I got my [Oh My ZSH!](http://ohmyz.sh/) working on [Conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) as my default console, with [agnoster](https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874) theme and there works perfectly. Then I tried to go an step forward and start using [Oh My ZSH!](http://ohmyz.sh/) in my [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) terminal and got some issues like this one:

[image: Error when [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)terminal start]

In my [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) settings I have this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin\\zsh.exe"
```

Also is happening with bash when try to use any command:

```
bash: ls: command not found
```

This is what I have in my **PATH** variable:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ConEmu:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu:/cygdrive/c/Program
Data/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/
Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Fi
les (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/To
ols/Binn:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
 SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn/ManagementSt
udio:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corpora
tion/PhysX/Common:%NVM_HOME%:%NVM_SYMLINK%:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/ddieppa/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windo
wsApps:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/ddieppa/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/c/nvm:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cygdrive/c/Users/ddiep
pa/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SQL Operations Studio/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/ddieppa/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft V
S Code Insiders/bin
```

How can I get [Oh My ZSH!](http://ohmyz.sh/) with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) to work on my [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) terminal?

Answer (score 4):

File -> Preferences -> Settings

```html
{
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows":   "C:\\Cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-lic", "cd $OLDPWD; exec zsh"]
}
```

The critical part is the third line; apparently the if you don't have it, the PATH does not have

```html
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.